# Problems with <> via an INNER JOIN query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a tag by its name, but only if a reference to it doesn't already exist in the relationship table:

```
SELECT
    tags.tag_id, tags.tag
FROM
    tags
INNER JOIN
    bookmarks_tags
ON
    (bookmarks_tags.user_id = tags.user_id)
WHERE
    (tags.user_id = '1')
AND
    (tags.tag LIKE '%Jose%')
AND
    (bookmarks_tags.tag_id NOT IN (tags.tag_id))
GROUP BY tags.tag_id
```

I've tried combinations of "!=", "<>", and the above, in just about every permutation I can think of, but none exclude "Jose", which they should do given that tag is present in the "tags" table, and the "bookmarks-tags" table, which contains the reference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a LEFT JOIN and exclude the rows which match:

```
SELECT tags.tag_id, tags.tag
FROM tags
    LEFT JOIN bookmarks_tags 
        ON bookmarks_tags.user_id = tags.user_id
            AND bookmarks_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE tags.user_id = 1 
    AND tags.tag LIKE '%Jose%'
    AND bookmarks_tags.tag_id IS NULL
```

Alternatively you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT tag_id, tag
FROM tags
WHERE user_id = 1 
    AND tag LIKE '%Jose%'
    AND tag_id IS NULL
    AND tag_id NOT IN (SELECT tag_id FROM bookmarks_tags WHERE user_id = 1)
```

I prefer the first option.

Comment: Richard, that's perfect. Thanks.